# codeigniter routes not working on ubuntu server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I'm working on a ubuntu server that installed by me. I have made a php web application using codeigniter frame work. most of the things working very well. but the thing is I can't use ulr like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'new_user'; ?>" >New User</a>
```

it is redirect me to an error page saying

```
The requested URL /sdbl/new_user was not found on this server.
```

my route.php file is looking something like this.

```
$route['new_user'] = "new_user/controller_new_user";
```

but when i type full url in the href="" like

```
<a href="index.php/new_user/controller_new_user" >New User</a>
```

This is working well.

i tried doing thousands things like editnig htacces file and so many. nothing works for me.

Comment: do you want to remove `index.php` from url?

Comment: yes and also i need to use something like 
$route['view_req_hr/:any'] 
i can't do this now :(

Comment: Did you see the andre answer? ans is it working?

Comment: yes it didn't help me boss. still the url needs that index.php thing

Comment: If not solved and index.php is not a problem, then use `site_url` instead of `baseurl()`. So url will have index.php.

Comment: @kumar_v still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), you should use an `.htaccess` file to remove the "index.php" from the URL, here's an example file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I don't know either, since you don't provide any info that can help to find out what's wrong here... did you create that `.htaccess` file and put it in your web directory (the same dir as `index.php`) ? Did you set the "AllowOverride" parameter in your server's configuration (which is needed to allow .htaccess usage) ? Did you enable the rewrite module in your server's configuration ?

Comment: Mr.Andre can you please tell me how to set that allowoveride parameter? and also how can i test it?

Comment: @Mr.Andre - i made those changes.
enabled rewrite by using this command "a2enmod rewrite"
and the allow override parameter set to all by editing the file /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: @Yasitha did you restart the HTTP server ? Does it work as expected now ?

Comment: yes i did restart
still the url only works when i type index.php after the base url

Comment: in my var/log/apache2/error_log
[Sun Dec 29 15:08:48 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/sdbl/

Comment: Your `index.php` should be in the root directory of the web server.

Comment: all my application files and folders are inside the /var/www/sdbl/ folder. is this the problem?
and also my www folder permission is set to root. will this also a problem?

Comment: @Yasitha yes, that's problematic. Move everything from /var/www/sdbl/ to /var/www.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I moved all the files to /var/www/ folder and now it is working. 
for my knowledge i like to know if there is several sites i need to put inside /www/ folder like /www/sdbl and /www/sdbl2 like wise does there is any option to do this? 

thanks in advance. hats off :)

Comment: If you have multiple sites then you should use [VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), that way you have a different root directory for each site (/var/www/site1 and /var/www/site2 for exemple), the .htaccess file stays the same.